# Replace a single character within a match via Regex

Tags: regex

I have a simple pattern that I am trying to do a find and replace on.  It needs to replace all dashes with periods when they are surrounded by numbers.

Replace the period in these:

```
3-54
32-11
111-4523mhz
```

Like So:

```
3.54
32.11
111.4523mhz
```

However, I do not want to replace the dash inside anything like these:

```
Example-One
A-Test
```

I have tried using the following:

```
preg_replace('/[0-9](-)[0-9]/', '.', $string);
```

However, this will replace the entire match instead of just the middle.  How do you only replace a portion of the match?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/([0-9])-([0-9])/', '$1.$2', $string);
```

Should do the trick :)

**Edit:** some more explanation:

By using `(` and `)` in a regular expression, you create a group. That group can be used in the replacement. `$1` get replaced with the first matched group, `$2` gets replaced with the second matched group and so on.

That means that if you would (just for example) change `'$1.$2'` to `'$2.$1'`, the operation would swap the two numbers.
That isn't useful behavior in your case, but perhaps it helps you understand the principle better.

Comment: Grouping is a great tool to have in your regex toolbox! Edit and added explanation much appreciated

Comment: For example in `kate` editor you could use `\1` instead $1 etc.

Comment: This seems to be a function of PHP, while the question seems to be about regex in general. While it seems like the OP targeted regexes in PHP since he accepted the answer, it would be good to have a language agnostic answer to fit the question.

Comment: `string.replace('/([0-9])-([0-9])/', '$1.$2')` works in Javascript

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the regex implementation you're using, you can use non-capturing groups:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=[0-9])-(?=[0-9])/', '.', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use back-references to retain the parts of the match you want to keep:

```
preg_replace('/([0-9])-([0-9])/', '$1.$2', $string);
```

Answer (score -2):

Below are couple of ways of achieving the same.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by Rituraj_Jain on 7/14/2017.
 */
public class Main {

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S)-(\\S)");
    private static final String input = "Test-TestBad-ManRituRaj-Jain";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        String s = matcher.replaceAll("$1 $2");
        System.out.println(s);

        System.out.println(input.replaceAll(pattern.pattern(), "$1 $2"));


    }
    public static void main1(String[] args) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        StringBuffer finalString = new StringBuffer();
        while(matcher.find()){
            String replace = matcher.group().replace("-", " ");
            matcher.appendReplacement(finalString, replace);
        }
        matcher.appendTail(finalString);
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println(finalString.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to restrict to numbers.

Comment: Yes, it is generic, so it will account for anything non space chars.