# Replace a specific character in a regex match

Tags: java, regex

How can I replace a specific character in a Regex match which is present multiple times.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638060/replace-a-single-character-within-a-match-via-regex?answertab=active#tab-top) post about it which helped me a lot, but it replaces only 1 character.
I would need it to replace all.

For example from this:

```
href="https://Link.com/test/Release+This+Has+Some+Pluses
Linkcom//test/Release+This+Has+Some+Pluses
```

To:

```
href="https://Link.com/test/Release%20This%20Has%20Some%20Pluses
Link.com/test/Release+This+Has+Some+Pluses
```

Here is what I got so far

```
Line.replaceAll("(https://Link.com/test/)(\w+)\+" , "$1%20")
```

But as I already mentioned. This only replaces one character and not all like this:

```
href="https://Link.com/display/release5/Release%20This+Has+Some+Pluses
Link.com/test/Release+This+Has+Some+Pluses
```

How would I replace all?

**EDIT**

Here is the code snippet from Java:

```java
public class ExchangeLink {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Mati\\Desktop\\test.txt");
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
            List<String> replaced = lines.map(line -> line.replaceAll("(href=\"https://link.com/test/)(\\w+)\\+", "$1$2%20")).collect(Collectors.toList());
            Files.write(path, replaced);
            lines.close();
            System.out.println("Find and Replace done!!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show a complete sample of the code you used? `replaceAll` arguments are strings so they are supposed to be in double quotes.

Comment: `replaceAll` replaces all occurrences. See https://regex101.com/r/vP3zBr/1 and https://ideone.com/ASXuve

Comment: why not `replaceAll("+", "=")`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to replace the + with a different character in HTML files but in links only, not the whole file.

Comment: @MAnouti I've added the code from Java

Comment: It's still not clear why it only replaces the first occurrence

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It replaces only the first occurrence because `replace('(\w+)\+' , '$1=')` only sees the first foo+ match. After that it ignores the rest. I should have added that the regex sees the text as Lines in my Code and after it's made one change in a line, it goes to the next one.

Comment: First of all you should use dubbel quotes and not single quotes and secondly I just tested your code with your examples and everything gets replaced. So you need to supply a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in 2 steps.

```
Pattern links = Pattern.compile("href=\"https://link.com/test/((\\w+)\\+?)+");
Matcher matcher = links.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    line = line.replace(matcher.group(), matcher.group().replace("+", "%20"));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `line = line.replace...`? or `lines = line.replace...`

Comment: Do it for every line. Pattern can be defined outside the stream, only needs to be compiled once.